# POST http://localhost:5000/my-server/capture-paypal-order 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use paypal payment in my website, every thing is going well but when i try to pay with sandbox personal account i get this error "`POST http://localhost:5000/my-server/capture-paypal-order 500 (Internal Server Error)`" when i log it to the console i got this message :

```json
Error: 
    {
       "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
       "details":[
          {
             "issue":"COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION",
             "description":"Transaction cannot be processed due to a possible compliance violation. To get more information about the transaction, call Customer Support."
          }
       ],
       "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
       "links":[
          {
             "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION",
             "rel":"information_link",
             "method":"GET"
          }
       ]
    }
```